# C++ read/write random access file using gcount() method

Tags: c++, fstream

Consider the code:

```
const int length = 1024 * 1024; //     1048576
char buffer[length];

fstream f;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    f.open("file.bin", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);

    f.read(buffer, length);

    int k = 0;
    while (f.gcount() > 0)
    {
        k++;
        cout << "Block #" << k << ": " << f.gcount() << " bytes" << endl;

        f.read(buffer, f.gcount());
    } // while

    f.close();

    return 0;

} // main
```

The size of the file "file.bin" is 2,895,872 bytes.
When I ran this code, the output is:

```
Block #1: 1048576 bytes
Block #2: 1048576 bytes
Block #3: 798720 bytes
```

Now, suppose that I want to do a useless thing: read each block and then write it again in the same file (in pratical terms this is a do nothing operation)

```
const int length = 1024 * 1024; //     1048576
char buffer[length];

fstream f;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    f.open("file.bin", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);

    f.read(buffer, length);

    int k = 0;
    while (f.gcount() > 0)
    {
        k++;
        cout << "Block #" << k << ": " << f.gcount() << " bytes" << endl;

// this is the code I added
        f.seekp(-f.gcount(), ios_base::cur); // move file pointer backwards
        f.write(buffer, f.gcount()); // write the buffer again <=> do nothing
// end of the code I added

        f.read(buffer, f.gcount());
    } // while

    f.close();

    return 0;

} // main
```

Now the output is

```
Block #1: 1048576 bytes
```

Why Block #2 and #3 are not listed?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The function [`seekp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/seekp/) seeks on the output sequence, but the output sequence didn't change due to the fact that you were just reading (which changes the input sequence).

I think the best thing to do update the output sequence each time you perform a read, I'm not sure if it will work but you might try:

```
// ...

f.read(buffer, length);
f.seekp(f.gcount(), ios_base::cur); // update output sequence

int k = 0;
while (f.gcount() > 0)
{
    k++;
    cout << "Block #" << k << ": " << f.gcount() << " bytes" << endl;

// this is the code I added
    f.seekp(-f.gcount(), ios_base::cur); // move file pointer backwards
    f.write(buffer, f.gcount()); // write the buffer again <=> do nothing
// end of the code I added

    f.read(buffer, f.gcount());
    f.seekp(f.gcount(), ios_base::cur); // update output sequence
}

// ...
```

Comment: Didn't work. One of the greatest confusions in C++ is that in files open for both input and output, seekp and seekg are the same thing just like tellp and tellg.